# Extend interface with common logic

Tags: php, interface, extension-methods, syntactic-sugar

Suppose I have,

```
interface Foo {

}

class FooClass implements Foo {

}
```

Is there a way I can add some logic to the interface outside of the `FooClass` so that I can do this:

```
$foo = new FooClass();
$foo->Bar();
```

where `Bar` is a method applicable to all `Foo`s? What I am asking for is something similar to [extension methods in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) but in my case I want to extend just interfaces.

I know I can add a custom static function `Bar` which accepts `Foo` as parameter but I want to know if there's anything in PHP which gives me the `$foo->Bar()` sugar.

**Edit:** I think I wasn't clear enough. I have a couple of similar interfaces (and many classes implementing them) from an external library. Changing them to abstract classes is not an option for me.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't use abstract class for that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the closest thing you can do is define the function and it's parameters in `interface Foo` (i.e. `public function Bar();`). The implementation of said function would then be required by any classes implementing it, but it would be entirely up to that class as to how it implemented it.

Comment: @MateoBarahona yes, I have interfaces, I want to extend them.

Comment: @War10ck the logic is common, I am trying to avoid implementing it in every class that implements Foo

Comment: @nawfal : but that's not what Interfaces stand for ! Abstract class, yes. Anyway, if you REALLY want to to so with an interface as super mother, maybe consider doing a intermediate class with the function, and extend it.

Comment: @nawfal To avoid the re-implementation in each class, you'll need to extend a class `abstract` or otherwise. Interfaces only support function definitions not the entire function declaration.

Comment: @MateoBarahona did you mean in the case of PHP? I know the concept of interfaces and I know it can be done in other languages and that it has its uses. I am asking if there a similar approach in PHP.

Comment: @nawfal : yes, I'm talking php here

Comment: @MateoBarahona thanks, that's worthy of an answer I believe. Liked the traits approach more in this case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you can get with PHP are the so called [traits](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

```
<?php
interface Foo {

}

trait myTraits {
        function bar() { echo "BarMethod"; }
}

class FooClass implements Foo {
        use myTraits;
}

$foo = new FooClass();
$foo->Bar();
?>
```

This will output "BarMethod".

Comment: This is a decent option. Though I will have to add "use myTraits;" in all classes, I think that's OK. Thanks.